# Acceder a props desde un componente a otro

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

quiero poder acceder a los valores que tiene este componente:

```
<Tbox
   title ='Calculo'
   count = {this.count(title)}
/>
```

por ejemplo acceder al valor que tenga la propiedad de 'title' y poder usarlo como parámetro para una función que esta dentro de la propiedad de count, el problema es que ya he intentado de varias formas pero aun no logro que funcione.

Answer (score 0):

No me queda muy clara tu pregunta, quieres pasar el valor de tu prop title a `this.count()` cuando estas usando el componente `Tbox` o dentro del componente?

```
const title = 'Calculo'

<Tbox
   title ={title}
   count = {() => this.count(title)}
/>
```

Porque podrias asignar el valor de title a una variable o constante si no vas a cambiar el valor despues y asi pasar ese mismo valor a `this.count`. Si te fijas se agrega un arrow function porque si no se ejecutaria esa funcion cuando el componente se renderiza.